# matching and merging columns of several dataframes in R

Tags: r

I have several data files as a result from a questionnaire and I want to merge the "rating" column of each file into a new one. However, not every datafile will contain the same items, so I want to do a string match depending on item name.

here is a reduced example of how three possible files look like:

df1:

```
word    rating
P_1          1
P_2          1
P_3          1
A_1          X
```

df2:

```
word    rating
P_2         2
P_3         2
P_4         2
A_3         Y
A_4         Z
```

df3:

```
word    rating
P_2         3
P_4         3
```

My desired output is:

```
word    rating_df1    rating_df2    rating_df3
P_1              1            
A_1              X 
P_2              1             2             3
P_3              1             2
A_3                            Y
P_4                            2             3   
A_4                            Z
```

I read through answers of similar questions and in the end ran the following code:

```
df1 <- read.table('1.txt', header=TRUE, sep="\t")
df2 <- read.table('2.txt', header=TRUE, sep="\t")
df3 <- read.table('3.txt', header=TRUE, sep="\t")

merged = Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y, all = TRUE, by = "word"), list(df1, df2, df3))
```

This does give me desired output as to how the columns are arranged. However, it sometimes repeats rows for an item that is rated in several files (e.g., P_2). I do not understand the pattern of this repetition.

I also don't quite understand the structure of the functions, so I'm sure the problem lies somewhere in there...

Can someone maybe explain to me what exactly the functions do? In the end I will merge much more than three files.

I hope my examples are somehow clear enough?

Thank you!

Comment: I have no repetition of rows here on my system. Please provide your data using `dput()` for instance.

Comment: ok, found the problem! yes, the repetition was only in my "real" data and I just realized that since my code for "word" was not as simple as e.g. P_1 as in my example here, there was another number added, that differed between the different datasets. I will remove that number first and then the output should work as in the example above... thanks